# How can I customize the ExtendedDescription view for DefaultOption?

Tags: gluon-mobile

If I set the `ExtendedDescription` text for a `DefaultOption` clicking the option opens a view where the text is displayed in an `HBox` and is centered there. I would like to customize the `HBox` area where the text is: align the text not only to center, color the text or bold/italicise parts of it, add a small image maybe...

I didn't see any API to access anything relating to customization except for maybe `OptionEditor` but when I try to call `editorFactoryProperty()` the optional is always empty. Am I supposed to create one myself and set it? What is the process for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far there is no API for the Extended View.

If you check it with [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/), you can see that the view nodes have custom style classes applied though, so you will be able to use lookups on runtime to get a hold of the `BorderPane` (id: `extended-pane`), the `HBox` at the top (id: `extended-top`), the one at the center (id: `extended-center`), and its `Text` child (styleClass: `extended-text`).

[image: Extended View]

Something like this should work:

```
viewProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
        if (nv != null && nv.getName().startsWith("Extended_View_Gender")) {
            BorderPane pane = (BorderPane) nv.lookup(".extended-pane");
            if (pane != null) {
                Text text = (Text) pane.lookup(".extended-text");
                text.setStyle("-fx-fill: red");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This causes the text in all extended views to be red. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. Is this supposed to let me individually style each option's extended view? Maybe I'm calling the wrong `viewProperty()`?

Comment: To customize different extended views, you will just have to check the view's name. In each case, the extended view will be named `"Extended_View_" + option.caption` plus some more indices related to the level. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: In version 5 there is no `getName`, what is the replacement?